# Linked List: Can't access last node, getting R6010 (C++, VS2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've got this templated Linked List class. When I add five elements, the 'size' data member says there are five elements but when I use the 'getAt()' function I can't seem to access the 5th node. It's giving me R6010 error (calling for abort). I can't seem to find an issue with the logic in the getAt() function. Maybe it's not actually adding the fifth one? Don't think so, though. Never seen this error before.

```
//LinkedList.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


/*
class: Node
description: holds an T in 'info' and a Node pointer in
             'next'. the building block of a linked list.
*/
template <typename T>
class Node{
public:
    T info;//holds the info value
    Node<T>* next;//holds a pointer to the next node in the list

    Node(T val);//constructor
};

/*  
function: constructor
param(s): T (value)
pre:
post: instantiates node, sets "next" pointer to NULL
exception(s):
return:
*/
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T val){//constructor, accepts a value to hold the info
    info = val;
    next = NULL;
}//end Node class


///////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////


/*
class: LinkedList
description: a list of linked T-type nodes. provides methods to add
             node and retrieve a node at a given location in the list. 
*/
template <typename T>
class LinkedList{
public:
    Node<T>* list;//points to the first node of the list
    int size;//the number of nodes in the list

    LinkedList();//default constructor
    ~LinkedList();//destructor
    void add(T addArg);//add a node
    T getAt(int getArg);//get a node at a position 'getArg'
    void updateAt(int getArg, T newData);
};//end LinkedList class

/*  
function: linked list default constructor
param(s): 
pre: 
post: list is instantiated, size is set to 0
exception(s): 
return: 
*/
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
    list = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

/*  
function: linked list destructor
param(s):
pre:
post: all nodes and pointer to the first node deleted
exception(s):
return:
*/
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList(){
    while(list != NULL){
        Node<T>* temp = list->next;
        delete list;
        list = temp;
    }
}

/*  
function: add
param(s): T (addArg)
pre: list is instantiated
post: new node has been added to the node, link of previous node
      has been set to the new node. if no nodes in list before
      adding, link of the new node is NULL
exception(s): 
return: void
*/
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::add(T addArg){
    if(size == 0){//if the list is empty
        Node<T>* next = new Node<T>(addArg);//create a new node
        list = next;//and set the 'list' pointer to it
        size++;//increment size of list
    }
    else if(size > 0){//if there's at least one node in the list
        Node<T>* temp = list;//create new node 
        while(temp->next != NULL){//traverse list to last node
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new Node<T>(addArg);//set the link of the last
                                      //node to a new node of value
                                      //addArg
        size++;//increment size of the list
    }
    else//throw exception, the list has a negative size value
        throw string("Size is negative for some reason...\n");
}

/*  
function: getAt
param(s): getArg(int, the position of the node to retrieve)
pre: list isn't empty
post: 
exception(s): throw out of bounds exception of getArg is negative 
              or out of bounds
return: value of the node at position 'getArg'
*/
template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::getAt(int getArg){
    if((getArg>=size)||(getArg<0))//getArg out of bounds
        throw string("Out of bounds 'get' argument");
    else{//getArg is acceptable
        Node<T>* temp = list;//create a temp pointer so as to not lose
                          // the pointer to the list
        for(int i = 1; i < getArg; i++){//traverse list until the
            temp = temp->next;          //sought-after node is found
        }
        return temp->info;//return the value of the sought-after node
    }
}

/*  
function: updateAt
param(s): getArg(int, the position of the node to retrieve)
          newData(T, new data)
pre: list isn't empty
post: info at node getArg is changed to 
exception(s): throw out of bounds exception of getArg is negative 
              or out of bounds
return: value of the node at position 'getArg'
*/
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::updateAt(int getArg, T newData){
    if((getArg>=size)||(getArg<0))//getArg out of bounds
        throw string("Out of bounds 'get' argument");
    else{//getArg is acceptable
        Node<T>* temp = list;//create a temp pointer so as to not lose
                          // the pointer to the list
        for(int j = 1; j < getArg; j++){//traverse list until the
            temp = temp->next;          //sought-after node is found
        }
        temp->info = newData;//return the value of the sought-after node
    }
}
```

Here's main

```
//main.cpp

void main(void)
{
    LinkedList<int> mine;
    mine.add(1);
    mine.add(2);
    mine.add(3);
    mine.add(4);
    mine.add(5);
    cout << "Size: " << mine.size << endl;

    int dem;
    for(int i = 1; i<= 5; i++)
    {
        dem = mine.getAt(i);
        cout << "i = " << i << endl << "val = " << dem << endl;
    }

    mine.updateAt(3, 10);
    for(int i = 1; i<= 5; i++)
    {
        dem = mine.getAt(i);
        cout << "i = " << i << endl << "val = " << dem << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing an out-of-bound index here:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
```

If you look at your `getAt`:

```
T LinkedList<T>::getAt(int getArg){
    if((getArg>=size)||(getArg<0))//getArg out of bounds
        throw string("Out of bounds 'get' argument");
```

It's 0-based not 1-based.

More appropriate would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ use zero-index. Therefor the for loop should be

```
for(int i = 0; i< 5; ++i)
```